# Numerical precision of arctan function

Tags: geometry, numerical-methods

I'm trying to convert points into spherical coordinates, do some filtering/manipulation of the points and convert them back into the Cartesian coordinate frame. These are my transformation equations into spherical coordinates:

$$
\begin{align}
r &= \sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}\\
\theta &= \arccos\left(\frac{z}{x^2+y^2+z^2}\right)\\
\phi &= \arctan\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)
\end{align}
$$

And to convert back to Cartesian coordinates:

$$
\begin{align}
x &= r\sin{\theta}\cos{\phi}\\
y &= r\sin{\theta}\sin{\phi}\\
z &= r \cos{\theta}
\end{align}
$$

However, after converting back to Cartesian coordinates, I notice a hole in my points along the $z$-axis (both in the positive $z$-axis and negataive $z$-axis directions). I suspect this is due to the imprecision of the $arctan$ function (I'm using the std version of atan2 in C++). Can anyone confirm my this? If so, does anyone know a way around it?

Comment: This question might be better on the Stack Overflow SE site: http://stackoverflow.com/ It sounds like you need a better library function.

Comment: Can you provide an example of this inaccuracy?  I do not seem to recall a problem with atan2 - I actually preferred this function way more than acos which for obvious reasons is fraught with difficulties.

Comment: There are other possible explanations for this, some mathematical.  You should give us an example.

Comment: How would you like an example? I can show you a picture of the data before transforming points to spherical coordinates and after transforming back to Cartesian coordinates.

Comment: Think of the geometry: $\theta$ is the angular variable along the great circle which is determined by $\phi$. When $\phi$ is such that you are at the north or south pole of the sphere, the great circle collapses to a point (the pole itself), and so $\theta$ is not well-defined. You should expect problems in this situation if you are not careful.

Comment: Sorry, I think I used a different convention for spherical coordinates than you did, so I think my $\theta$ and $\phi$ should be interchanged. The geometric point is the same, though.

Comment: (answer converted in a comment) Concerning $\theta$ and $\phi$ the expressions should be :
$$\theta = \arccos\left(\frac{z}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}\right)\\
\phi = \arctan\left(\frac yx\right)$$
(the last one by dividing $y$ and $x$, the first one using $\cos(\theta)=\dfrac zr$). Supposing your code correct the problem was probably explained by Victor Liu : $\;\arccos\,$ may have a large relative error while evaluating $\arccos(1-\epsilon)$. Computing acos(1-0.5e-8)*1e4, acos(1-0.5e-10)*1e5, acos(1-0.5e-12)*1e6 using gcc on a mac I obtained  0.9999999974, 1.0000000414, 1.0000444493
0.9996002812.

Comment: Use $\theta=\arctan\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}z\right)$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: I was just adding the same suggestion (for the case $x^2+y^2\ll z^2$ at least)... :-)

Comment: @RaymondManzoni: this works well for all values, especially with an atan2 function.

Answer (score 3):

If anything, I would suspect the `acos` function since you need to compute its argument very precisely near the z-axis to ensure that you remain within the domain $[-1,1]$. Due to the sensitivity of `acos` near the endpoints of its domain to small numerical errors (the slope approaches vertical), I would suggest computing $\theta$ using the `asin` function when you detect that the $z$ coordinate dominates the $x$ and $y$ coordinates.

Currently, you are essentially taking a dot product of your normalized vector $(x,y,z)/|(x,y,z)|$ with the unit $z$ vector $(0,0,1)$, which gets you $\cos\theta$. Instead, compute the magnitude of the cross product of your normalized vector with the unit $z$ vector, which gets you $\sin\theta$. The slope of `asin` is around $1$ near $0$, leading to much improved numerical sensitivity.

Comment: Victor, thanks for your response. What you are saying makes a lot of sense if the slope of the acos() function approaches 1 near the endpoints. I'm going to run some numbers and post with what I find.

Comment: I think you mean the slope approaches $-\infty$ near the endpoints. In general, the `atan2` function should be very accurate unless your points are _very_ close to the origin.

Comment: Yes sorry you're right. As acos() approaches 1 the slope approaches negative infinity

Answer (score 2):

A good rule of thumb is: don't ever use acos or asin on arguments whose magnitudes may be greater than $\sqrt 2/2$.
Since you're using atan2 which is a solid tool, you can get the two angles robustly as:

$$
\begin{align}
\theta &= \mathrm{atan2}\left({z},\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)\\
\phi &= \mathrm{atan2}\left({y},{x}\right)
\end{align}
$$

The rest of your formulas look good.